# Statistical test for count data in three different environments

Tags: anova, poisson-distribution, count-data, ecology, many-categories

I'm an undergrad student working on a small research project while studying abroad and I was looking for a statistical test that I could use to compare species richness between three forest types.

I collected data on the species richness of moss (i.e. number of unique moss species) for 4 replicates of three forest types (birch, spruce, pine), giving me a total of 12 forest plots in total. In each replicate, I sampled 10 quadrats, thus 120 quadrats in total. I want to see how species richness differs between birch, spruce, and pine forests.

So if I know the total species richness for each of the 4 replicates of each forest type, how could I compare the richness of the different forest types by running a stat test in R?

Example Data: *not my actual data*

Spruce1 = 4 unique species,
Spruce2 = 5 unique species,
Spruce3 = 5 unique species,
Spruce4 = 4 unique species.

Birch1 = 3 unique species,
Birch2 = 2 unique species,
Birch3 = 6 unique species,
Birch4 = 3 unique species.

Pine1 = 3 unique species,
Pine2 = 3 unique species,
Pine3 = 4 unique species,
Pine4 = 3 unique species.

^^Is there a statistical difference in species diversity in the different forest types?

This might be a pretty simple question, but I am pretty new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you please provide some extra details regarding the real data? how many types of forests, how many measurements in each?

Comment: in addition, you do need to understand what's your null hypothesis, because this will help figuring out the type of test you need to conduct. Do you want to compare them all at once? perform pairwise comparison? are the sample sizes in each group the same? is the variance assumed to be equal in all groups?

Comment: Is it the case that the analysis would be done on the 12 plots ?  That is, that there's no need to consider the variability within quadrants for a given plot ?

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a rarefaction. Take a look at the `iNext` R package that implements interpolation and extrapolation

Comment: I don't see how rarefaction would help test for differences in species richness? Rarefaction is used to  account for differential sampling intensity, which doesn't seem to apply here...?